# Updating Table with System Date

Tags: sql

My question is very simple:

I have a column named "DateProcessed". Whenever User Clicks a Button, the column should be updated for each row with the current System.Date.

Here is my code:

```
update dbo.JobStatus SET DateShipTransmitProcessed = ???? WHERE JobTableId = @JobTableId
```

What should go in ????. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the database you're using ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ANSI standard would be to use current_timestamp, which should work for MySql, SQL Server, and any other ANSI compliant RDBMS.

```
update dbo.JobStatus SET DateShipTransmitProcessed = current_timestamp WHERE JobTableId = @JobTableId
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL server..

```
update dbo.JobStatus SET DateShipTransmitProcessed = GetDate() WHERE JobTableId = @JobTableId
```